# How can I change the appearance of a navbar in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, navigation, wordpress-theming

I'm using this theme for a site: http://demo.woothemes.com/?name=theonepager.

However, when viewing in a mobile or smaller view the dropdown navbar looks a bit plain and I'd like to change this. Is it possible to change the appearance of the navbar through the dashboard settings, or would I need to alter the css directly?

Comment: "Change the appearance" is a very broad statement.  What *specifically* would you like to change?

Comment: Be specific and the best solution will be to ask the theme author, look up in the documentation, write the css.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass **class or id**  of **ul** tag in wp_nav_menu hook, will change design view.

Ex:

```
 <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                                'theme_location' => 'primary',
                                'menu_class'     => 'primary-menu',
                              'items_wrap'    => '<ul class="myMenu" id="myCustomid">%3$s</ul>'
                             ) 
           );
                                    ?>
```